# Future methods in flow actions

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, future, queueable-apex

I've two flow actions which both make HTTP callouts. The second action depends on the output of the first.

However, since future methods don't return a value, I'm unable to use the second action in the flow. I've explored `Queueable` interface, but it only gives the job id, I really need to get the response from action 1 somehow.

What is the best way to achieve this? One crude way I can think of is setting up a custom object to hold the job id & result of action 1, then action 2 queries the custom object to get the results of action 1 after certain delay. Are there better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a Pause element immediately before the callout; this ends the current transaction and allows you to pick up asynchronously. After that, you should be able to perform the callout *synchronously*, return that result immediately, then continue through the rest of the flow.